# Javascript Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected token }

Tags: javascript

Tried to finish function exercise. Checked several times by myself and on SO but didn't understand why this Error appears at line 11. Why there should be curly brace there?

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }"

```
<body>
<p id="myFunctionPrint"> </p>
<p id="printFunctions"> </p>
<p> Sum is: <span id="Sum"></span> Sub is: <span id="myResult2"></span> Multiple is: <span id="myResult3"></span> Divide is <span id="myResult4"></span>
</p>
<br><br> Enter number: &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="text" id="Number1" />
<br><br> Enter other number: &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="text" id="Number2" />
<button onclick="Add(" Number1 ", "Number2 ")"> Get result </button>
<script>
    function Add(a, b){
        a = parseInt(document.getElementById("Number1").value, 10);
        b = parseInt(document.getElementById("Number2").value, 10);
        c = a + b;
        return document.write(c);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: `document.write` doesn't belong into an event handler in any circumstances, if you want to preserve the page. `dw` is purposed to create a new document, not to update an existing document.

Comment: if you want to use quotes inside quotes you have to escape them `onclick="Add(\" Number1 \", \"Number2 \")"`

Comment: NB: You try to pass the two arguments, but then don't use them in the function. Better is to separate HTML from code, and bind event handlers from code.

Comment: @emed, you have to HTML escape them, which would be `onclick="Add(&quot;Number1&quot;, &quot;Number2&quot;)"`, which is why you should avoid adding JS in HTML, it's too easy to make a mistake with the encodings.

Comment: @zzzzBov oh, yep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix your HTML by either:

Escaping the quotes in the onclick:

```
<button onclick="Add(&quot;Number1&quot;, &quot;Number2&quot;);"> Get result </button>
```

or using single quotations for the parameter values:

```
<button onclick="Add('Number1', 'Number2');"> Get result </button>
```

The above should fix the problem. However there is also the recommendation for you to remove the parameters from the method. You don't need them since you are reading values from the input elements anyway and not using the values you are sending.

So if you want... Remove the parameters from the function definition and instead init the variables inside the funcition:

```
function Add(){
        var a = parseInt(document.getElementById("Number1").value, 10);
        var b = parseInt(document.getElementById("Number2").value, 10);
        var c = a + b;
        return document.body.innerHTML += c;
    }
```

Then change the button HTML like so:

```
<button onclick="Add();"> Get result </button>
```

[edit] I think it's important to note that parseInt() could fail if the element is not found or if the value inside the element does not represent an integer value.

Comment: `\"` in the attribute is the wrong escape sequence.

Comment: @zzzzBov you'll need to elaborate. the syntax is correct.

Comment: If you were escaping JavaScript, but you're not escaping JavaScript there. [You need to escape HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48326912/javascript-uncaught-syntax-error-unexpected-token/48327400?noredirect=1#comment83639360_48326912); so no, the syntax isn't correct.

Comment: @zzzzBov I see. Thank you for bringing the error to attention.